# How to pass global variables and Go Context in Go handlerfunc

Tags: go, redis, httphandler, go-gorm

So, I'm kind of new to programming and Go, so forgive me if I do something wrong. I'm building a rest API with Go. I'm using GORM to access my Postresql DB and I want to use Redis to store JSON web keys. Go Context is something I'm yet to understand, but I need it to set things in Redis according to the docs like this:

```
Set(ctx Context, key string, value interface{}, expiration Duration) *StatusCmd
```

As I see it now I can do two things to access Redis, Go Context and the DB in the handler without giving it 3 parameters. Pass a Struct like below to the handler

```
type env struct {
    ctx *context.Context
    db  *gorm.DB
    rdb *redis.Client
}

handler.ListItems(env{ctx: context.TODO(), db: gorm.DB, redis.Client})
```

or store the variables in the Go Context

```
ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "db", gorm.DB)
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "rdb", redis.Client)

handler.ListItems(ctx)
```

So my question is: What is the best practice in this scenario, and why?

Comment: What does ListItems return, a handler? or a list of items? Because if it returns a handler then you most probably don't want to give *it* a context.

Comment: It returns a handler, I thought that you should always initiate the context in the _func main_ ? Should I do that inside the handler itself?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context *"Package context defines the Context type, which carries deadlines, cancellation signals, and other **request-scoped** values across API boundaries and between processes."*

Comment: Note also that each `*http.Request` passed in to a handler already holds its own [context](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) which you can utilize if you need to.